# Is there a tool that can draw architecture diagram of projects from Visual Studio 2010 solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml

Is there a tool that can draw architecture diagram of projects from Visual Studio 2010 solution?

I want a diagram that shows how each project of the solution interacts with eachother grouped by the folder of the solution? Is there a tool that can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have **Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate**, you can use dependency graphs or layer diagrams to help you accomplish this. If you have this version and want to do this for C/C++ code, you'll also need the **Visualization & Modeling Feature Pack**, which you can get as an MSDN subscriber.

**Dependency Graphs**

- On the **Architecture** menu, choose **Generate Dependency Graph** -> **By
  Assembly**. This will give you a dependency graph of the entire solution organized by project. Though their contents are not organized by folders automatically, they are organized by namespaces. You can then organize the contents manually to represent folders.

  -or-
- Create a blank dependency graph. In **Architecture Explorer**, go to **Solution View** to browse the solution, and then drag projects and their items to the dependency graph.

For more information, see [How to: Generate Dependency Graphs for .NET Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409453.aspx) and [How to: Generate Dependency Graphs for C and C++ Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657798.aspx)

**Layer Diagrams**

1. Create a blank layer diagram, and then drag from **Architecture Explorer** to create the project layers.
2. To represent folders, add layers inside the project layers and then drag folders from **Architecture Explorer** to map them to those nested layers.
3. To see the dependencies, right-click the diagram, and then choose **Generate Dependencies**.

For more information, see [How to: Create Layer Diagrams from Artifacts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465141.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The NDepend tool for .NET developers comes with both a dependency graph and a dependency matrix and integrates in VS. You can [download and use the free trial edition](http://www.ndepend.com/NDependDownload.aspx) of NDepend for a while.

In the NDepend start page you'll see a *Analyze VS solutions and VS projects* that will let you analyze readily your code.

[More on NDepend Dependency Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx)
[image]

[More on NDepend Dependency Matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx):
[image]

*Disclaimer: I am part of the tool team*